# How to remove duplicate entry and count duplicate value from a json

Tags: jquery, json

I have json object and I try to remove duplicate entry based upon `RoomId` and count duplicate data.

I try:

```js
var listobj = [{
    "RoomId": 8195,
    "RoomName": "S-403 - Standard Room",
    "Rate": 3000,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "PostinDate": "2023-03-31T18:15:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "RoomId": 8196,
    "RoomName": "S-404 - Standard Room",
    "Rate": 3000,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "PostinDate": "2023-03-31T18:15:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "RoomId": 8195,
    "RoomName": "S-403 - Standard Room",
    "Rate": 3000,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "PostinDate": "2023-04-01T18:15:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "RoomId": 8196,
    "RoomName": "S-404 - Standard Room",
    "Rate": 3000,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "PostinDate": "2023-04-01T18:15:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "RoomId": 8195,
    "RoomName": "S-403 - Standard Room",
    "Rate": 3000,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "PostinDate": "2023-04-02T18:15:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "RoomId": 8196,
    "RoomName": "S-404 - Standard Room",
    "Rate": 3000,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "PostinDate": "2023-04-02T18:15:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "RoomId": 8195,
    "RoomName": "S-403 - Standard Room",
    "Rate": 3000,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "PostinDate": "2023-04-03T18:15:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "RoomId": 8196,
    "RoomName": "S-404 - Standard Room",
    "Rate": 3000,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "PostinDate": "2023-04-03T18:15:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "RoomId": 8195,
    "RoomName": "S-403 - Standard Room",
    "Rate": 3000,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "PostinDate": "2023-04-04T18:15:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "RoomId": 8196,
    "RoomName": "S-404 - Standard Room",
    "Rate": 3000,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "PostinDate": "2023-04-04T18:15:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "RoomId": 8195,
    "RoomName": "S-403 - Standard Room",
    "Rate": 3000,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "PostinDate": "2023-04-05T18:15:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "RoomId": 8196,
    "RoomName": "S-404 - Standard Room",
    "Rate": 3000,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "PostinDate": "2023-04-05T18:15:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "RoomId": 8195,
    "RoomName": "S-403 - Standard Room",
    "Rate": 3000,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "PostinDate": "2023-04-06T18:15:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "RoomId": 8196,
    "RoomName": "S-404 - Standard Room",
    "Rate": 3000,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "PostinDate": "2023-04-06T18:15:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "RoomId": 8195,
    "RoomName": "S-403 - Standard Room",
    "Rate": 3000,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "PostinDate": "2023-04-07T18:15:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "RoomId": 8196,
    "RoomName": "S-404 - Standard Room",
    "Rate": 3000,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "PostinDate": "2023-04-07T18:15:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "RoomId": 8195,
    "RoomName": "S-403 - Standard Room",
    "Rate": 3000,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "PostinDate": "2023-04-08T18:15:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "RoomId": 8196,
    "RoomName": "S-404 - Standard Room",
    "Rate": 3000,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "PostinDate": "2023-04-08T18:15:00.000Z"
  }
]


function groupByID(arr) {
  var groupBy = {};
  $.each(arr, function() {
    groupBy[this.RoomId] = 1 + (groupBy[this.RoomId] || 0);

  });
  return groupBy;
}

function createArray(obj) {
  var arr = [];
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key, val) {
    arr.push({
      RoomId: key,
      RoomName: obj.RoomName,
      Quantity: obj[key]
    });
  });
  return arr;
}
var resObj = groupByID(listobj);
var resArray = createArray(resObj);
console.log(resArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Expected Out Put:

```
var out =[
 {
        "RoomId": 8195,
        "RoomName": "S-403 - Standard Room",
        "Rate": 3000,
        "Quantity": 9,
        "PostinDate": "2023-04-08T18:15:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "RoomId": 8196,
        "RoomName": "S-404 - Standard Room",
        "Rate": 3000,
        "Quantity": 9,
        "PostinDate": "2023-04-08T18:15:00.000Z"
    }
]
```

How to catch other field like `RoomName`,`Rate` from json.

Comment: So, copy the data to a dictionary where "RoomId" is the key, then convert that back to a list.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. Filter json based on `roomId`, count and update filtered json.

```js
var listobj = [{
    "RoomId": 8195,
    "RoomName": "S-403 - Standard Room",
    "Rate": 3000,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "PostinDate": "2023-03-31T18:15:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "RoomId": 8196,
    "RoomName": "S-404 - Standard Room",
    "Rate": 3000,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "PostinDate": "2023-03-31T18:15:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "RoomId": 8195,
    "RoomName": "S-403 - Standard Room",
    "Rate": 3000,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "PostinDate": "2023-04-01T18:15:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "RoomId": 8196,
    "RoomName": "S-404 - Standard Room",
    "Rate": 3000,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "PostinDate": "2023-04-01T18:15:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "RoomId": 8195,
    "RoomName": "S-403 - Standard Room",
    "Rate": 3000,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "PostinDate": "2023-04-02T18:15:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "RoomId": 8196,
    "RoomName": "S-404 - Standard Room",
    "Rate": 3000,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "PostinDate": "2023-04-02T18:15:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "RoomId": 8195,
    "RoomName": "S-403 - Standard Room",
    "Rate": 3000,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "PostinDate": "2023-04-03T18:15:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "RoomId": 8196,
    "RoomName": "S-404 - Standard Room",
    "Rate": 3000,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "PostinDate": "2023-04-03T18:15:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "RoomId": 8195,
    "RoomName": "S-403 - Standard Room",
    "Rate": 3000,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "PostinDate": "2023-04-04T18:15:00.000Z"
  },

  {
    "RoomId": 8195,
    "RoomName": "S-403 - Standard Room",
    "Rate": 3000,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "PostinDate": "2023-04-05T18:15:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "RoomId": 8196,
    "RoomName": "S-404 - Standard Room",
    "Rate": 3000,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "PostinDate": "2023-04-05T18:15:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "RoomId": 8195,
    "RoomName": "S-403 - Standard Room",
    "Rate": 3000,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "PostinDate": "2023-04-06T18:15:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "RoomId": 8196,
    "RoomName": "S-404 - Standard Room",
    "Rate": 3000,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "PostinDate": "2023-04-06T18:15:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "RoomId": 8195,
    "RoomName": "S-403 - Standard Room",
    "Rate": 3000,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "PostinDate": "2023-04-07T18:15:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "RoomId": 8195,
    "RoomName": "S-403 - Standard Room",
    "Rate": 3000,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "PostinDate": "2023-04-08T18:15:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "RoomId": 8196,
    "RoomName": "S-404 - Standard Room",
    "Rate": 3000,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "PostinDate": "2023-04-08T18:15:00.000Z"
  }
]


function groupByID(arr) {
  var groupBy = {};
  $.each(arr, function() {
    groupBy[this.RoomId] = 1 + (groupBy[this.RoomId] || 0);

  });
  return groupBy;
}

function countQuantity(obj) {
  var arr = [];
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key, val) {
    arr.push({
      Quantity: obj[key]

    });
  });
  return arr;
}
var resObj = groupByID(listobj);
var quantityArray = countQuantity(resObj);

const result = listobj.filter(
  (thing, index, self) =>
  index ===
  self.findIndex((t) => t.RoomId === thing.RoomId)
);

result.forEach(function(i, x) {
  i.Quantity = quantityArray[x].Quantity;

});
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

.

Answer (score 0):

```
const roomList = [
  { roomId: 1, roomName: "Room 1" },
  { roomId: 2, roomName: "Room 2" },
  { roomId: 3, roomName: "Room 3" },
  { roomId: 1, roomName: "Room 1" },
  { roomId: 4, roomName: "Room 4" },
];
const uniqueRooms = Array.from(new Set(roomList.map(room => room.roomName)))
  .map(roomName => {
    return roomList.find(room => room.roomName === roomName);
  });
console.log(uniqueRooms)
```